# Spring Controller sending image to client results in 406

Tags: spring, image, arrays, http-status-code-406

I'm trying to send an image to the front end upon request, it works if i put it in the request body as part JSON, but i want to use image/png, makes more sense, but i get a 406 when i try that.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RESTPaths.EQUIPMENT_FILE_GET_IMAGE + "/{equipmentId}", method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody byte[] insertDataFile(@PathVariable("equipmentId") final Long equipmentId)
        throws InternalServerError {
    return equipmentFileService.getImage(equipmentId);
}
```

Test (client):

```
mockMvc.perform(
            get(RESTPaths.EQUIPMENT_FILE_CONTROLLER + RESTPaths.EQUIPMENT_FILE_GET_IMAGE + "/" + equipment.getId())
                    .with(httpBasic("user", "password")).accept(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
                    .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)).andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Can you please clarify which version of Spring you are using, this works with 4.1 +

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the mvc annotation in servlet-context.xml file which registers a ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter

```
<mvc:annotation-driven> <mvc:message-converters> <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"> <property name="supportedMediaTypes"> <list> <value>image/jpeg</value> <value>image/png</value> </list> </property> </bean> </mvc:message-converters> </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Did the proposed solution solve your problem or is it still not working

Comment: I tried that (with a java configuration), didn't help, i'm, looking into my version now

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RESTPaths.EQUIPMENT_FILE_GET_IMAGE + "/{equipmentId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public  ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable("equipmentId") final Long equipmentId)
        throws InternalServerError {
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(equipmentFileService.getImage(equipmentId), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```